# how to populate and validate array of inputs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a project using Laravel 10 where I need to insert multiple data into `detail_transaction` table.

this is my input data

```html
<form action="/transaction/create" method="POST">
@csrf
<div data-slug-barang="cctv-panasonic-fhd-bluetooth-5">
  <input type="hidden" name="nama[]" data-field="nama" value="CCTV Panasonic FHD Bluetooth 5" />
  <input type="hidden" name="slug[]" data-field="slug" value="cctv-panasonic-fhd-bluetooth-5" />
  <input type="hidden" name="stok[]" data-field="stok" value="25" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hargaModal[]" data-field="hargaModal" value="100000" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hargaJual[]" data-field="hargaJual" value="120000" />
  <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" data-field="qty" value="20" />
</div>
<div data-slug-barang="lampu-led-phillips-12-watt">
  <input type="hidden" name="nama[]" data-field="nama" value="Lampu LED Phillips 12 Watt" />
  <input type="hidden" name="slug[]" data-field="slug" value="lampu-led-phillips-12-watt" />
  <input type="hidden" name="stok[]" data-field="stok" value="50" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hargaModal[]" data-field="hargaModal" value="25000" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hargaJual[]" data-field="hargaJual" value="30000" />
  <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" data-field="qty" value="30" />
</div>
```

when I submit the form, the above code will result in this kind of variable when I use `$request->dd()`:

[image: result of dd]

I have no idea on how to populate and validate the variables using Eloquent ORM. the above code seems like an obsolete way to do this.. I believe Laravel already has something to make this easier, but I'm very new to Laravel so I don't even know where to look. can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Do not paste data as an image, because the image will eventually go down, rendering the question unusable... When you are not sure about something basic, check the documentation, [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation) and [basic eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models). Try something with it and if you cannot make it work, come to use with code please

Comment: Maybe [start here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation)? There's info about validating arrays too.

Comment: There are so many examples here on SO, and the docs are good.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting inputs as arrays , `nama` for example is an array.
To validate arrays values inside your controller you use the Asterisk symbol (*).

```
$request->validate([
            'nama.*'=> 'required|min:3',
            'qty.*'=> 'required|integer',

        ]);
```

The above code sample is an example of how you validate values inside nama array and qty array.

To get the values and save it inside the database you have to iterate through the arrays values.

```
 $nama_array=$request->input('nama');
 $slug_array=$request->input('slug');
 $stok_array=$request->input('stok');

 $nama_count=count($nama_array);
 for ($x = 0; $x < $nama_count; $x++) {
     $item_nama=$nama_array[$x];
     $item_slug=$slug_array[$x];
     $item_stok=$stok_array[$x];

     $item=new Item();
     $item->nama=$item_nama;
     $item->slug=$item_slug;
     $item->stok=$item_stok;
     $item->save();
  }
```